# Carto-VL animation controls not showing up on map

Tags: widget, cartodb

The sample Carto-VL animation control code doesn't appear on my animated map.

I'm creating an animation of tree population change since the last ice age in Carto VL, and I want the user to be able to change the duration and play/pause the animation. I've pasted the code from the example pages into my map.

```
const $progressRange = document.getElementById('js-progress-range');
const $playButton = document.getElementById('js-play-button');
const $pauseButton = document.getElementById('js-pause-button');
const $durationRange = document.getElementById('js-duration-range');
const $currentTime = document.getElementById('js-current-time');

// Listen to interaction events with the UI
$playButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
viz.variables.animation.play();
});

$pauseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
viz.variables.animation.pause();
});

$durationRange.addEventListener('change', () => {
viz.variables.duration = parseInt($durationRange.value, 10);
});

// Update progress bar each 100 milliseconds
function updateProgress () {
$progressRange.value = viz.variables.animation.getProgressPct();
$currentTime.innerText = viz.variables.animation.getProgressValue();
}

setInterval(updateProgress, 100);
```

I expect the animation control box to show up on the map, but it only appears if there's an error in the code causing the map not to appear. Even then, I cannot interact with it.

Comment: Anna, could you please share the whole piece of code, with HTML included? It would be also very useful to see it online, in something like a https://codepen.io/

Comment: I figured it out! The animation control box was under the map.